How to achieve wrapping align left+right and solve the spacing problem after emdash?
I’m currently working on a LaTeX document where I have defined a new command \entry that takes two arguments:
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1} — \hfill{#2}}

where it is used in this document like this:
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.7cm,right=4.7cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1} — \hfill{#2}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{asfdsaf}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

\entry{wefwefwwfw}{normyecm sdfsdafs  ergerga graer aerhehetha heheterhrhreher aeferargegera htrhtrhrath pfmvrc jhqukldlxxahw kpojw quiluh jhichogw cdmttfsiovral} \\ 
\entry{wefwefwwfw}{normyecm sdfsdafs  ergerga graer aerhehetha heheterhrhreher aeferargegera htrhtrhrath pfmvrc jhqukldlxxahw kpojw quiluh jhichogw cdmttfsiovral} \\ 
... (there are more than 500+ same `\entry{wefwefwwfw}{...} \\` entries in the entire section)...

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}

This command is used to create entries that are nicely aligned to the left and right, which is a combination of flushleft and flushright. This is something that ragged2e wouldn’t provide. It also prevents texts from overlapping to the other side of the twoside page after subsequent \entry like this: 
However, I’m facing an issue with the spacing after the emdash. When I use \hfill, there is a space after the emdash which I don’t want. If I remove \hfill to deal with the emdash problem, there is no spacing after the emdash, but then there is the problem of the text overlapping, where the overlapping text problem becomes more apparent after past the ~300+ entry mark with overfull errors like this:

with the console log full of overfull errors like this:
Overfull \hbox (14.7117pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 90--95
\T1/ppl/b/n/10 (-20) wefwefwwfw  \T1/ppl/m/n/10 (-20) ^^V normyecm sdfs-dafs er
g-

Is there a solution to this that can let the new command achieve the wrapping align left+right, and solves the spacing problem after the emdash consistently throughout the entire section?

it is hard to guess your intention here. \hfill is only very indirectly related to line breaking it is a command that inserts an arbitrarily large space, and it is producing a large space, so it is working as designed, and if you don't want the space simply don't use \hfill

you can not really test line breaking using nonsense words such as aerhehetha  as they will not hyphenate using the English hyphenation patterns so it is quite likely there will be no feasible way to break the lines without getting over full boxes that stick into the margin or the next column.

You are forcing excessive space with \hfill as allowing arbitrarily large horizontal space is the sole function of that command.
Removing the \hfill and using ~ so you do not get a line break next to the dash produces quite reasonable justification, given that the nonsense words mean that there are few possibilities for hyphenation.
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}

\usepackage[top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=3.7cm,right=4.7cm,columnsep=30pt]{geometry}
% only needed in old latex \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\fancyhead[L]{}
\fancyhead[R]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[C]{\textbf{\textsf{\thepage}}}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\newcommand{\entry}[2]{\markboth{#1}{#1}\textbf{#1}~—~{#2}}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{asfdsaf}
\begin{multicols*}{2}

  \entry{wefwefwwfw}{normyecm sdfsdafs  ergerga graer aerhehetha heheterhrhreher
    aeferargegera htrhtrhrath pfmvrc jhqukldlxxahw kpojw quiluh jhichogw cdmttfsiovral}
  % never end a paragraph with \\  latex warns about badness 10000 if you do

\end{multicols*}

\end{document}



My section has 500+ entries in there so removing the \hfill from \newcommand produces a lot of overfull errors where LaTeX compiler will ignore the rules and have texts overlapping on the other side of twosides past the ~250th-ish mark. This doesn't seem to be a memory issue however because if \hfill is present in the \newcommand rule, then the texts overlapping problem will not occur. To reproduce this example, you can try paste 600+ times the \entry{wefwefwwfw}{.... line (including the // in it) then you'll see the overlapping effect happening at the last few pages.

@swiftenjoyer no sorry, latex never ignores rules, the rules are just set inappropriately in your document. You  should  be using something like \sloppy to allow white space to strech more if you have text that is difficult to linebreak, \hfill is just explicitly allowing arbitrarily lareg white space at the point that this question asks to avoid adding space so not using \hfill at that point is the only answer possible. The only function of \hfill is to do what you ask does not happen, it adds space at that point.

@swiftenjoyer The linebreaking in each paragraph is totally indepent so you do not need to make an example with 250 paragraphs, just make an example with a single bad paragraph which does not linebreak with the default settings. Never ebd a paragraph with \\  that is always wrong.

Adding \sloppy before the \begin{multicols}{2} lines worked!
